# Inserting data into PostgreSQL jsonb column with Daper.Net and NPGSQL

Tags: c#, postgresql, dapper, npgsql

I'm trying to insert JSON data into a JSONB PostgreSQL column using Dapper.Net.

The [NPGSQL Documentation for JSONB](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/faq.html) gives specific instructions to use the `NpgsqlDbType.Jsonb` datatype.

With Dapper, I'm trying to add this as a custom parameter without success.

```
using (var conn = myconnection)
{
    var sql = "INSERT INTO mytable (jsonbody) VALUES (@jb);";
    dp =  new DynamicParameters();
    dp.Add("jb", stringOfJsonData, (DbType)NpgsqlDbType.Jsonb);
    await conn.ExecuteAsync(sql,dp);                    
}
```

The error I'm receiving is 
`System.NotSupportedException : The parameter type DbType.36 isn't supported by PostgreSQL or Npgsql`

Any suggestions on how to use these two libraries together for JSONB?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NpgsqlDbType and DbType are two different enums, you can't simply cast one into the other...

You'll have to make for set the NpgsqlDbType property on the NpgsqlParameters it creates and send. IIRC there's a way to specify custom parameters.

Comment: You can use [this overload of AddWithValue](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/api/Npgsql.NpgsqlParameterCollection.html#Npgsql_NpgsqlParameterCollection_AddWithValue_NpgsqlTypes_NpgsqlDbType_System_Object_), for example. Or instantiate an NpgsqlParameter yourself, set its NpgsqlDbType property and add it to the command's parameter collection.

Answer (score 13):

It appears that changing the SQL statement to the following fixed it.

```
var sql = "INSERT INTO mytable (jsonbody) VALUES (CAST(@jb AS json));";
```

Also, there's no need to specify the type in the parameter mapping.

```
dp.Add("jb", stringOfJsonData)
```