# Net core dapper insert model inside model error: the member cannot be used as a parameter value

Tags: sql, asp.net-core, dapper

Below, I have my main model MyModel.

Options is a property of type Options.

In PostGres Options is a jsonb column.

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public Options Options { get; set; } = new Options();
}
```

Options model:

```
public class Options
{
    public string Test { get; set; }
}
```

Using Dapper I insert like this:

```
public async Task Create(MyModel model)
{
string sql = "insert into MyModel (id, options) values (@id, @options)"
....
```

I get this error:

"The member Options of type MyApp.Models.Api.Options cannot be used as a parameter value"

How does Dapper know about the options model I am sending in?
Should I be serialising Options before sending to Dapper?

I cannot find many examples of this kind of thing where there's a model inside a model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using CAST(@options as json) in my SQL sorted the error.

Answer (score 1):

Dapper knows about the options model because you define its name as sql param (@options), it attempts to map each model property into a matching query parameter.

You can either define your own type handler `ITypeHandler` which handles the serialization or you pass the model like this:

```
new 
{
  model.Id,
  options = JsonConvert.SerializeJson(model.Options)
}
```

See here how to create a custom type: https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/blob/master/Dapper.Tests/TypeHandlerTests.cs#L101

Comment: But options is of type Options and cannot be converted to a string when it is being serialised (unless I am missing something)

Comment: The purpose of a JSON serializer is to convert an arbitrary object into a JSON representation (Which is a string). Eg.: JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Options { Test = "Foo" }) =  {"Test":"Foo"}

Comment: Understood - my point is that model.Options is not a string type so cannot be set to a serialised string.

Comment: Could you elaborate "cannot be set to a serialized string"? PostGres accepts a json formatted string for the jsonb column type, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51144790/1028323

Comment: Using CAST(@options as json) in my SQL sorted the error.